# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For what values of $x$ is the series absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent and divergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)x^n$$

---

Let $a_n=\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)x^n$. The root test gives

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)=|x|e.$$

To converge absolutely, we need $|x|e<1\Leftrightarrow x\in(-\frac{1}{e},\frac{1}{e}).$

Now I need to check for the endpoints. For $x=-1/e$ I get the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)\frac{1}{e^n}(-1)^n$$

I need to examine this with Leibniz test for alternating series and I have to check two things:

1. $a_n$ is decreasing.
2. $a_n\rightarrow0,$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$

Condition 2 is trivial, so let's only examine the limit. Stirlings formula gives

$$a_n=\left(\frac{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}(1+\xi_n)}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)\frac{1}{e^n}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}(1+\xi_n)}{e^{2n}}+e^{n^2\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}.$$

Before I let $n\rightarrow \infty$, note that I can Taylor expand

$$n^2\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=n^2\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O(1/n^3)\right)=n-\frac{1}{2}+O(1/n).$$

So I have that

$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}(1+\xi_n)}{e^{2n}}+n-\frac{1}{2}+O(1/n),$$

letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ I get

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0+\infty-\frac{1}{2}+0=\infty,$$

thus the series is divergent for $x=-1/e$.

**Questions:**

1. Is the above entierly correct? Maple says that

   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)\frac{1}{e^n}=1$$

but I just got it to equal infinity using the Stirling approximation. Why did I get a different answer?

2. For the endpoint $x=1/e$, I can't use Leibniz test for alternating
   series since it's not alternating anymore. What test would be apropriate for this one?

**Note:** No need for fancy advanced solutions using theorems and rewritings I've never heard of. If you want to contribute, keep the answer limited to usage of Stirlings and Taylors and basic series tests.

Comment: I don't get what happens in the first lines after you say "the root test gives"

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I don't see it.. Where is $1/n$ in the power then?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut oh I got it

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **point 1**

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}\sim \frac{\sqrt {2\pi n}}{e^n} \quad \quad \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\sim \frac{e^n}{\sqrt{e}}$$

thus

$$\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)\frac{1}{e^n}\sim\frac{\sqrt {2\pi n}}{e^{2n}}+\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{e}}\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$

For **point 2**

See point 1.

Comment: Avoid splitting infinite series when convergence of both sub-series hasn't been proved yet. It's sloppy and misleading.

Comment: Also if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are both positive?

Comment: Thus it should be better simply observe that$ \left(\frac{n!}{n^n}+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)\sim e^n$ and work on the whole series?

Comment: It's alright if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive, but this is not the case here since $x$ may be negative. (Reasoning on positive $x$ will only yield the radius of convergence, with work left at the boundary).

Comment: @GabrielRomon Thank for your observations!